# How to execute a function an empty name argument?

Tags: swift

I have a function with following signature:

```
func example(_ description: String = "", () -> Void) {
}
```

but the compiler produce a following error:

> error: unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'

So, I update the function signature:

```
func example(_ description: String = "", _: () -> Void) {
}
```

Question is, how can I execute the empty labeled parameter. If it's impossible then why the compiler allows an argument to be empty named?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the function as

```
func example(_ description: String = "", _: () -> Void) {
}
```

then you can indeed not call the closure from within the function.

But you can have an empty argument label and a separate parameter name which is used inside the function:

```
func example(_ description: String = "", _ closure: () -> Void) {
    closure()
}

example("Hello", { print("Hello world") })
```

For more information, see [“Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names”](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) in the Swift reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think this shouldn't be available (maybe a bug), because it makes no sense. The `_` is reserved thing and you can't really use it as a variable.

---

But if you want, you can use `_` as valid parameter name by surrounding underscore with **`**

```
func example(_ description: String = "", `_`: () -> Void) {
    `_`()
}

example { print("printed") }
```